# Programmatically setting space between tabBarItem title and bottom layout in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, tabbar

I want to set space between tabBarItem title and bottom in Swift.

I've tried to set space between tabBarItem image and top layout like this         `vc.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)`. now my tab bar  looks like this [image]

I want there to be more space between the tabBarItem title and the bottom than it is now.

Answer (score 2):

I found solution `UITabBarItem.appearance().titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: -10)`